# Determining the number of images or if there are any images within a newspaper article

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

This is a kind of similar question compared to my previous one. I'm interested in determining the number of images/pictures within a newspaper article like the one given below.
Using something like:

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (42,42))
```

I managed to extract a single image and save it as an image-file.

[image]

However, I were not able to get the number of images in a given newspaper article. It would even be sufficient to tell whether there are images within an article.

Is it somehow possible to determine the number of "huge" areas that are not just black/white or is there any other recommended way of determining the amount of pictures - or at least if there are any pictures - within an image?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Please post a representative sample input so we don't waste our time answering only to find the text runs vertically, or the scans aren't vertical, or the images are greyscale or the background is patterened. Thank you. As it stands, the answer is to find blue areas.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm sorry. I hope the new picture is more representative?

Comment: If you do as you say and remove black and white areas, I fear your text will show up as pictures since it is underlined with wavy red lines.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Uff. I'm sorry once again.